# What is the name of the application that shows Bluetooth device status?

Tags: command-line, bluetooth

What is the **name of the application** - used by Ubuntu 16.04 - which actually shows the Bluetooth devices?

I have two USB dongle Bluetooth adapters installed and am getting conflicting info. Only one USB dongle shows as "paired" (with what?) type "Computer". And it is "off" and cannot be turned "on".

I can get there through **Bluetooth Settings** and the window title is "Bluetooth".

I like to bypass the flaky GUI with CLI commands, but I need the real app name.

Comment: have you tried blueman

Comment: Not used blueman, but successfully installed blueman-manager.
It looks as combination of CLI  and GUI - gives results in “terminal” - will need some time to analyze. 
The GUI is pretty much same as other  package , identifies only one bluetooth device and gets stuck in “pairing”.   
Not exactly 100% solution , but appreciate the helpful suggestion.

Comment: I guess you may need to specify the desktop environment to get the answer to this. For working with Bluetooth via CLI, I have recently discovered `bluetoothctl`, but I don't think this answers your question (actually, personally I'm not sure what your goal is here - do you want to disable the confusing indicator or fix it, or find out where it is getting its information, or, just interact with your Bluetooth devices from the command line?)